# Ecryptfs Recovery but filename issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to restore an encrypted home directory from an external drive (taken from a broken machine). I've done it before, but this time I can't get it to un-encrypt the filenames!

Any help on where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated...

**Recover Passphrase**

```
root@t42:/mnt/se/home/hcooper# ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /mnt/se/var/lib/ecryptfs/hcooper/wrapped-passphrase <password>
Warning: Using default salt value (undefined in ~/.ecryptfsrc)
0eeeabd98b712xxxxxxxc99615aeed3
```

**Mount ~/.Private**

```
root@t42:/mnt/se/home/hcooper# mount -t ecryptfs .Private priv-mount/
Passphrase: <Copy and paste>
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32 (not loaded)
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32 (not loaded)
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24 (not loaded)
 4) twofish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32 (not loaded)
 5) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32 (not loaded)
 6) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16 (not loaded)
Selection [aes]: 
Select key bytes: 
 1) 16
 2) 32
 3) 24
Selection [16]: 
Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: 
Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: y
Filname Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [355a8158f7263d73]: 
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_fnek_sig=355a8158f7263d73
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=355a8158f7263d73
Mounted eCryptfs
```

**But files still encrypted!**

```
root@t42:/mnt/se/home/hcooper# ls priv-mount/ | head
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat01azIzg2-Bmv09aTP.798yk--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat02bjNe2K9A9yAtDtqVR2fKE--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat03lQpO4z6uUwD9WsQiJJmN---
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat03Tdy2UfXOFXqg59QPgiufk--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat03YCBiTiBPhUITveL61Ig5---
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat04U4m3v8nyfkYBzR0gIlurU--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat05hOO7o-TwsvxYPcbsuFduk--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat05IyxqDYKNvnaGQCucqCwR---
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat08Sn-h2I7Ve.H9QIQtJe3EE--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbV5bgYtAXkGUQkHQDy-741RhF0Oj9RLat0aMjHBO9ledaiSZ6VMVYfJE--
```

**Update:** I've managed to get the broken disk into single user mode, and when I "su - hcooper" and run *ecrypt-mount-private* it prompts me for my login password, then mounts .Private fine! So there must be something in my methology in manually mounting it that is wrong. Are the cipher types correct? Ummh.